# How to get the number of character in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea and I need to take each one of the field's characters to translate it into another.
But for this purpose I need to browse in the JTextArea.

So I thought of a simple loop like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= t.length(); i++) { ... }
```

but the `length()` function is not appropriate and I can't find one which is.

If anyone has already encountered this problem, I'd like a bit of help with it.

Comment: what's **t** in your case?

Comment: The JTexteArea. But i've got my answer. I shall use textArea.getText() and then work with the text i've exctracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the String content of a `JTextArea` field just use `textArea.getText()`, and then use that string as you usually do, e.g. getting its length with `length()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the length function in the Text of the jTextArea like this

```
jTextField.getText().length()
```