# When a JTextField reaches a certain amount of characters it moves onto the next one

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am making a gift code app and i wanted to know if there was a way to make the TextField your typing in move to the next TextField when you reach a certain amount of characters. So if there were 4 textfields next to each other when i fill the first one with 4 characters instead of hitting tab it moves on to the next jtextfield and so on till it reaches the end

Comment: do you know how to detect when text area has 4 characters ? do you know how to focus a textarea programmatically ? then you can do it .can you show your codes ?

Comment: No i do not, and what code would you like? All it is is JTextField textField = new JTextField(3); And then i add it to the JPanel.

Comment: here is 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723257/how-to-set-focus-on-jtextfield and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582795/how-to-get-the-number-of-character-in-a-jtextarea

Comment: I came up with a pretty bad solution but at least it works.

Comment: This concept is demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477999/jtextarea-filters-and-or-inputs-of-time-000000-java/25496932#25496932)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're basically asking can be easily achieved by using a `DocumentListener`, for example...

```
public class MoveFocusForwardHandler implements DocumentListener {

    private int maxLength;

    public MoveFocusForwardHandler(int maxLength) {
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public int getMaxLength() {
        return maxLength;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        documentChanged(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        documentChanged(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        documentChanged(e);
    }

    protected void documentChanged(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (getMaxLength() > 0) {
            if (e.getDocument().getLength() >= getMaxLength()) {
                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477999/jtextarea-filters-and-or-inputs-of-time-000000-java/25496932#25496932)